# Input RSS link and read titles (links) and save to user in database

Tags: php, html, css, xml, rss

I am creating a new web app/service, one of the features of this service is being able to add rss links to your account (when logged in) and it will retrieve the titles and display them in a list (max 10 or so of the latest).

Is there any way to allow the user to add a RSS feed URL and it will add it to there account and then display it in a list, so they can read the latest news etc (titles and then click on the link to read the full article on the site). How would I go about this and how would I save it to there account so when they come back it's still there (The feed URL, when they come back it will show the latest. Caching?).

*Edit:*

- User inputs a link to an RSS feed.
- The site displays the latest article titles and links from that feed
- The site save that URL to the database so when they come back it's still there.

*Note* I have a MySQL database with the list of members and can create other tables, the site is written in PHP, HTML, CSS etc.

Thanks for any help! Have looked around for a while but nothing seems to be a clear tutorial.

Comment: Yes, this can be done but your question is too broad. Break it down into the various steps and then search StackOverflow. I am pretty sure all of it has been answered before. For instance, to read an RSS feed you can use an XML parser.

Comment: Also state what you have tried so far.

Comment: I voted to close this because it isn't a good fit for this website.  We do appreciate your attempt to clean it up.  The answer provided will help you with the hardest part of your question, structuring your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an attempt at database normalization, I would use a structure that had 3 tables.

```
tbl_Users
   - id
   - username

tbl_Feeds
   - id
   - feed_name
   - feed_url

tbl_Users_Feeds
   - id
   - user_id
   - feed_id
```

This allows you to limit data redundancy.